# Connecting multiple devices to AWS MacOS instances

Tags: ios, xcode, adb, tvos

I have a bunch of AWS EC2 Mac Mini instances. My objective is to trigger my XCUITests on the devices using xcodebuild test-without-building. I am struggling to find a solution for running a test on a device with any instance. For example, in the case of android, I use adb to connect and disconnect from 1 instance to another, and I use ADB_VENDOR_KEYS to keep the same adbkey.

How do I achieve the same in the case of iOS and tvOS?